# Inferring Azure VM properties from string using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

Given an Azure VM size as string (e.g. "STANDARD_A4_v2") I would like to programmatically infer available memory and number of vCPUs. I've looked through [azure-mgmt-compute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/?view=azure-python) but can't find what I'm looking for.
I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52061293/get-virtual-machine-sizes-list-in-json-format-using-azure-sdk-for-python) using a ComputeManagementClient to iterate over all available VM sizes, but that's not what I need and furthermore in my case I only have access to Azure Batch credentials. Do I have to role my own (at least for vCPUs) following the [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/vm-naming-conventions)?

Many thanks,

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you have seen is what you need. The `virtual_machine_sizes` only have one function and it's the `list`. So you need to find your real VM size in the list. For example:

```
compute_client = CompteManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
vmSizes = compute_client.virtual_machine_sizes.list(location)
for vmSize in vmSizes:
  if(vmSize.name == "STANDARD_A4_v2")
    print("number of vCPU: " + vmSize.number_of_cores)
    print("available memory: " + vmSize.memory_in_mb)
```

And naming conventions are the rules that how does Azure define the VM size. You just need to read it to understand the VM size.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I saw that logic in the post I linked. However in my case, I only have Azure Batch credentials, so I can't even initialize a CompteManagementClient(). Sure, I can parse the number of cores just from the name, but unfortunately I can't do that for memory size. Any idea idea how else to get that list (without subscription id etc.)?

Comment: @Andreas Can you share your credential for Azure Batch? Which role do you have? You can only find the sizes in the document without a subscription, not in code.

Comment: Thanks Charles. That answers it I guess.

Comment: @Andreas OK, if it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Hi Charles, I'll accept this answer. The only caveat is that you can't achieve the above just with just Batch credentials, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @Andreas Actually, I didn't understand what do you mean the Batch credential. It will works if you have the credential of the subscription or group.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Azure command line and get the result directly e.g.
`az vm List-sizes -l AustraliaEast`

this gives me following result

[image: Screenshot of output]

Document you can refer to --  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-list-sizes

Note you need to login using 'Az login' first before you can execute the above command

Comment: Thanks. In my case I need to do this from within a Python environment, which only holds Azure Batch credentials